# MY SQL does not pull data past midnight UTC

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, case, utc

I am really having issue showing the items. I have two different times(they are in UTC).

FOR Eg: startTime - 15:00:00(in UTC) and cutOffTime - 03:00:00(in UTC and supposed to be up to 3am UTC next morning). My local timezone is EST. The issue I am having is after 8pm(EST) when next day start at UTC. My items does not shows up. Here is my sql query. I am pulling startTime and cutOffTime from table2.  MY server is in UTC as well.

```
SELECT a.id, a.column1, a.catID, b.startTime, b.cutOffTime, IFNULL(b.`column2`, 'everyday') as 'availableDays'
FROM table1 a
RIGHT JOIN table2 b on a.catID = b.catID
WHERE id = 012
and CASE WHEN b.startTime IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', b.startTime) < NOW() ELSE 1 END
and CASE WHEN b.cutOffTime IS NOT NULL THEN If((b.startTime is not NULL AND b.cutOffTime < b.startTime), DATE_ADD(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', b.cutOffTime), INTERVAL 24 HOUR), CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', b.cutOffTime)) > NOW() ELSE 1 END
HAVING availableDays in ('everyday', 'wednesday')
Order by a.column1 ASC;
```

My table2 is like this:

```
catID Cat   startTime  cutOffTime
1.    Test  15:00:00   03:00:00
2.    Test2  null       null
3.    Test3  15:00:00   null
```

Suppose it is 8:30pm EST(which is 00:30:00 UTC) then I am expecting to get all the results. Now, It is only returning me 2 and 3.

Comment: check phpinfo(): for datetimezone and also check if datetimezone is set in any php file in your scripts... or in .htaccess or php.ini

Comment: when you `select NOW()` (in the same environment as your query is running), what timezone does it seem to be returning in?

Comment: @ysth it returns in UTC for NOW()

Comment: please edit your question to show some sample data (working and non-working) and expected and actual results for that sample data

Comment: @ysth please check

Comment: setting up your query and your sample data in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=35159d657a5359ab021287fb6a1d244e it appears to be working.  I suspect you are having a problem with either now()/curdate() *not* in fact being in UTC (note that whatever is running your query could be setting a session timezone that changes these) or there is an issue with how you are checking availableDays (which you don't show at all in your sample data)

Comment: I suggest you remove the HAVING clause and also add NOW() and CURDATE() to what your query returns; that will tell you if either of those are issues

Comment: @ysth I have already tried adding curTime() as 'curTime', CURDATE() as 'curDate', NOW() as 'nowTime' to my sql statement and it looks fine and also available is everyday for all of them

Comment: maybe also add `CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', b.startTime) AS start_date_time` and `If((b.startTime is not NULL AND b.cutOffTime < b.startTime), DATE_ADD(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', b.cutOffTime), INTERVAL 24 HOUR), CONCAT(CURDATE(),' ', b.cutOffTime)) AS end_date_time` to your select fields and remove the CASE conditions from your where so you get all rows and see if the added fields look right?

Comment: see if you can modify my fiddle to duplicate the problem and show the new fiddle url if you do?